# How to export multiple selected worksheets to another workbook using VBA

Tags: vba, export

I have a source excel file which contains worksheets starting with "TYPICAL" name.
I also have a code to export the "TYPICAL" worksheet to another Excel file using the Getopenfile name. As a part of code, I have to rename the source worksheet as value contained in cell "E3" and current date.

Attached code works fine for me, but I can not select multiple "TYPICAL" sheets and export. Can any one suggest a way to loop through the selected work sheets?

```
Sub export()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Dim Sht As Worksheet
Dim dt As String
Dim mntg As String
Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook
Set Sht = Selection.Worksheet
Dim shtname As String
'
shtname = CStr(Sht.Name)
dt = CStr(Format(Date, "DDMMYY"))
If Left(shtname, 7) = "TYPICAL" Then
    mntg = CStr(Range("E2").Value)
    Sht.Name = mntg & "_" & dt
    FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
    (Title:="choose a Excel file to insert selected Typical File", _
    FileFilter:="*.xlsx (*.xlsx),")
'
    If FileToOpen = False Then
        MsgBox "No File Specified.", vbExclamation, "ERROR"
        Sht.Name = shtname
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FileToOpen)
    End If
    wb1.Activate
    Sht.Copy After:=wb2.Sheets(wb2.Sheets.Count)
    wb2.Save
    wb2.Close
Else
    MsgBox "This is not a Typical File for Export", vbExclamation, "ERROR"
End If
Sht.Name = shtname
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```